# Python , Convolution

Tags: python, convolution, cross-correlation

I want to take the part of mat (matrix) after every three slides. The code I have is taking the part of matrix after one slide.
I want to take the first 3 by 3 part of the matrix and then slide 3 columns to the right and take 3 by 3 part and so on, going through all the matrix.

```
n1=np.array(([1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[12,13,14,15,16,17],[18,19,20,21,22,23],[24,25,26,27,28,29],[30,31,32,33,34,35]))
print(n1)
k=3
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            mat = n1[i:i+k, j:j+k]
            print(mat)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be indented correctly? Could you add an example input and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slicing on both rows and cols like the code bellow...
Check out the docs [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_slicing.asp#:%7E:text=From%20both%20elements%2C%20slice%20index%201%20to%20index%204%20(not%20included)%2C%20this%20will%20return%20a%202%2DD%20array%3A)

```
import numpy as np

n1=np.array(([1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[12,13,14,15,16,17],[18,19,20,21,22,23],[24,25,26,27,28,29],[30,31,32,33,34,35]))
print(n1)

MAX_WIDTH = 3
MAX_HEIGHT = 3

for r in range(0, len(n1[0]), MAX_HEIGHT):
    for c in range(0, len(n1), MAX_WIDTH):
        print(n1[r:r+MAX_HEIGHT, c:c+MAX_WIDTH])
```